# Neural Network Programming, Searching for a good & simple game to train network for

Tags: java, neural-network

I am programming a program that creates simple neural networks. To be able to tie it deeply into the game, I am looking for a (simple 2D) game which is written in Java and open source. I have looked for one, but could not find a fitting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple tic tac toe game?

here is one from Github https://github.com/IhorKlimov/TicTacToe

Edit :-
here is an other one with a few more 2d games https://github.com/wouterken/JavaGames

hope that helps

Comment: I'd like a second one, maybe something where there is no algorithm for winning all the time. But I'll do it with this one for now, thank you!

Comment: no Probs @kaesaecracker , i have added a new link that has six more links :)